# Advice for writing a simple number triangle, only with recursion, no loops?

Tags: c++, recursion

So I have already written a function to write a number pyramid of variable height using several for loops and it works perfectly.

Here's an example of the kind of pyramids I'm talking about:

User Enters 4

```
      1 

    1 2 1

  1 2 3 2 1 

1 2 3 4 3 2 1
```

So I do indeed need to pad the left side with whitespace.

My problem is **I can't get it to work with recursion only**, no loops. I can't even think of a place to start in terms of recursion, really. I know I need a base case, as well as a way to approach that base case.

Should I write multiple recursive functions, or is there a way to do it with just one? (In addition to main, I mean.)

Here's what I have so far (it's not much at all):

```
void givepyramid(int lines);  //lines = Number of lines in pyramid (4 in example above)
{
     if lines == 1;
        cout << (//all the spaces needed)<<1;
     else
         cout << (I'm not too sure on how to go about this here.)
}
```

Any advice would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Get it to print *without* the leading spaces *first* (i.e. left justified). Get a handle on that, and the rest will be easy.

Comment: Can you not use loops at all, or just not use them to iterate over each line?

Comment: None at all, which is pretty tough for me. So thank you very much for your idea, but since it uses for loops, that wouldn't work. 

I'm going to try what whoz said and see what happens. Thank you both so far!

Comment: I've updated my answer to remove all loops.

Comment: My suggestion:  Search StackOverflow and the web for "c++ triangle print".  This is a common homework assignment.  Also search for "C++ Pascals triangle".

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution which draws pretty triangles without using loops:

```
#include <iostream>

void printRowNumbers( unsigned int n, unsigned int max )
{
    if ( n < max ) {
        std::cout << n << ' ';
        printRowNumbers( n + 1, max );
    }
    std::cout << n << ' ';
}

void drawTriangle( unsigned int n, unsigned int indent = 0 )
{
    if ( n > 1 ) {
        drawTriangle( n - 1, indent + 2 );
    }
    std::cout << std::string( indent, ' ' );
    printRowNumbers( 1, n );
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

The main idea is that there are two problems really which you'd usually tackle using loops:

1. Printing a row of numbers (without any particular indentation) like `1 2 3 2 1` or `1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1`. The key idea is that you aren't only printing the numbers up to a maximum value and back, you are in fact printing the numbers from some start value (which seems to be always `1` here) up to a maximum and then back to the start value.

   The insight is that printing such a "number mirror" from 1 to 5 and back is the same thing as printing 1, then printing a mirror from 2 to 5, then printing 1 again. And printing a mirror from 2 to 5 is the same as printing a 2, then doing a mirror from 3 to 5, then printing 2 again. And so on, up to the point where your minimum value is the same as the maximum, in which case you just print that number (that's your base case).
2. Printing something a number of times, each time on a new line with an ever decreasing indentation. We would need a function which can print something (say, a letter) a number of times - each time, on its own line and with ever-decreasing indentation. The last line is not indented at all. The simple case is printing just one line - in that case you don't have any indentation at all. Printing two lines would be the same thing as printing one line first with an indentation of, say, 2 - and then printing the line again. Printing three lines means printing two lines with an indentation of 2 first (which in turn means printing one line with an indentation of four!), then the third line with no indentation.

   Our code just happens to not print some random letter, instead the `drawTriangle` function takes care of getting the indentation right (and printing a newline) but lets `printRowNumbers` print the actual numbers.

As you can see, I didn't use a terribly analytical approach (it's possible to rewrite any loop into a recursion, so you could've written a loop and then mechanically transform it into a recursion by following some rules). Instead, I just did a few experiments by hand like "How does doing this two times differ from doing it just once, and how does doing it thrice differ from doing it twice" and then spot a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this code, but you could do something like this. It doesn't make use of any loops. This will print out an inverted pyramid, so I will leave the un-inverting part as an exercise for the reader.

```
void givepyramid(int lines)
{
    giveIndentedPyramid(lines, 0);
}

void giveIndentedPyramid(int line, int indentation)
{
    printIndentationRecursive(indentation);

    if(line > 0)
    {
        printLineRecursiveUp(1, line);
        printLineRecursiveDown(line);

        cout << endl;
        giveIndentedPyramid(line-1, indentation+2);
    }
}

void printIndentationRecursive(int indentation)
{
    /*
    for(int i = 0; i < indentation; i++)
    {
        cout << " ";
    }
    */
    if(indentation > 0)
    {
        cout << " ";
        printIndentationRecursive(indentation-1);
    }
}

void printLineRecursiveUp(int current, int line)
{
    /*
    for(int i = 1; i < line; i++)
    {
        cout << i << " ";
    }
    */
    if(current < line)
    {
        cout << current << " ";
        printLineRecursiveUp(current + 1, line);
    }
}

void printLineRecursiveDown(int line)
{
    if(line > 0)
    {
        cout << line << " ";
        printLineRecursiveDown(current - 1, line);
    }
}
```

Keep in mind this is untested code, so treat it as pseudo-code that you can use as a guideline to learn how to use recursion.

Comment: It's just a small issue, but for line > 9 there will exist a number which takes up more than 1 character column. I guess you could avoid this by increasing the indentation by 2 plus the log of the original line count. So for 10, it will indent by 3 every time, to accommodate for the 2-column number that will be produced.

Comment: Yea, you may have to account for that. See [this](http://obtalk.wordpress.com/2013/02/28/c-count-the-number-of-digits-in-an-integer/) page for a good example of how to count the number of digits in a number, should you need to account for this.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what you mean by the functions "printLineRecursiveUp" and "...down". They aren't defined so I didn't know what they did.

Comment: @user1745840 They are defined, maybe you have to scroll down a little bit? See the scroll bar on the right side of the code?

Comment: Haha I feel dumb... Thank you cory, let me see what I can do about learning recursion so this all makes sense. Also so I can flip it right side up!

Answer (score 0):

Works for numbers > 10, and fully without loops.

PS:C++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>


void gen_numbers(int len, int number, std::string &ans) {

    if (len > 1) {
        ans.append(std::to_string(number));
        ans.push_back(' ');
        gen_numbers(len - 1, number + 1, ans);
        ans.push_back(' ');
        ans.append(std::to_string(number));
    }
    if (len == 1)
        ans.append(std::to_string(number));

}

void print_spaces(int number) {
    std::cout << " ";
    if (number)
        print_spaces(number - 1);
}

void draw (int line, int depth) {
    if (line > 1) {
        draw(line - 1, depth);
    }

    print_spaces(2 * (depth - line));
    std::string ans;
    gen_numbers(line, 1, ans);
    std::cout << ans;
    print_spaces(depth - line);
    std::cout << std::endl;
}



int main() {
    draw(12, 12);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created folowing solution. 
It works with number of lines more 10.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> 
using namespace std;

void buildLine(int countline, int iteration)
{
 cout << string((countline-iteration),'\t');


 for(int i = 0; i < iteration; ++i)
 {
  cout << i+1 << "\t";
 }

 for(int i = iteration-1; i > 0; --i)
 {
   cout << i << "\t";
 }

 cout << string(countline-iteration,'\t') << endl;

 buildLine(countline,++iteration);

}

void buildPyramid(int lines)
{
 buildLine(lines, 1);
}


int main() {

   buildPyramid(11); 
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use two different recursive functions, which may or may not be reducible to a single recursive function. The example below can be edited to pad the left relatively simply and is left as an exercise. Essentially, you want to build the rows of the string on the left and right separately, then join them around the center number.

```
std::string buildString(int i, bool side)
{
    if(i < 1)
    {
        return "";
    }
    if(i == 1)
    {
        return "1";
    }
    if(i > 1)
    {
        std::ostringstream s;
        s << i;
        if(side == false) // left build
        {
             return buildString(i - 1, false) + " " + s.str();
        }
        if(side == true) // right build
        {
             return s.str() + " " + BuildString(i - 1, true);
        }
     }
 }

 //pass is function the expected length as well in order to enable padding
 void buildPyramid(int i /*, int max */)
 {
     if(i < 1)
     {
          return;
     }
     if(i > 1)
     {
          //by calling build pyramid recursively and falling through to the print statement after, you can cause the top of the pyramid to print first without looping
          buildPyramid(i - 1);
     }
     //the center number of each row is added here since it's the only number that isn't duplicated. By storing the resultant string in an ostringstream you can check the length and add padding.
     std::cout << buildString(i - 1, false) << " " << i << " " << buildString(i - 1, true);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple and recursive function without loops:

```
void printTree(int maxLevel, int currLevel = 0, int currPos = 1)
{
    if(currLevel>maxLevel)
        return;
    if(currPos<(maxLevel-currLevel))
    {
        cout<<'\t';
        printTree(maxLevel, currLevel, ++currPos);
    }
    else if(currPos<(maxLevel-currLevel + currLevel*2)-1)
    {
        cout<<((maxLevel - currPos)<=0?(currPos - maxLevel)+2:(maxLevel - currPos))<<'\t';
        printTree(maxLevel, currLevel, ++currPos);
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<endl;
        printTree(maxLevel, ++currLevel, 0);
    }
}
```

For your example, call the function as `printTree(4)`

Answer (score 0):

You may replace

```
for (int i = 0; i != N; ++i) {
    body(i, localVars);
}
```

by

```
void body_rec(int N, int i, LocalVars& localVars)
{
    if (i == N) return;
    body(i, localvars);
    body_rec(N, i + 1, localVars)
}
```